# Inconsistency in API data which is developed in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am developing an API using JAVA SpringBoot, which will return response in JSON format. I am facing data inconsistency in response.

I am returning data like this

```
 {
     "type": "Plan",
     "programs":[
         {
            .....
            "courses":[
              {......}
              iam geting data
            ]
         }
     ]

 }
```

Where as, **a few times** same API is producing data with empty courses like below.

```
 {
     "type": "Plan",
     "programs":[
         {
            .....
            "courses":[]
         }
     ]

 }
```

Could you please give your thoughts on what scenarios can bring this kind of behaviour

---

**DB:** Postgres

**Running in:** Kubernetes, Memory: 1024M

**Number of Rows retrieving from DB query**: 505 rows

Comment: are these two responses are for the same request parameters?

Comment: @StackVictor There is no change in API URL request. Every thing including parameter are same

Comment: Could you please post the logs of your app when it can't get data? `kubectl logs pod-name`